# Popmodal from overriden back button

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having some issues having my back button properly pop my modal after a user acknowledged that they will lose their changes if they do so. I suppose the issue lies in how to properly await the async method within a method that cannot be async due to how it is coded.

In my code behind I have the following method:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            Task<bool> confirm = DisplayAlert("Are you sure?", "All unsaved changes will be lost", "I'm Sure", "Cancel");
            confirm.ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if(x.Result)
                {
                    var task = Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                    task.Wait();
                }
            });
            
            return true;
        }
```

I can see that it does properly hit my breakpoint inside if the user has clicked "I'm Sure". However, after doing that the modal still remains on the page.

I call my modal using the following method (it is wrapped in a `NavigationPage` as I wanted to be able to leverage `Toolbar` items, if this is an anti pattern please let me know)

```
private async void EditSwipeItem_Invoked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var unitOfWork = container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
            var invoked = sender as SwipeItem;
            var element = invoked.BindingContext as InventoryModel;
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new AddEditInventoryList(true, "8dc9e483-1d63-4629-b386-680ad7c9a324", element.InventoryId, unitOfWork)));
        }
```

The code for the `backbutton` is based off of what I wrote for the `CancelToolBar_Clicked`, and it works correctly (That is, the modal is popped after the user acknowledges the prompt).

```
private async void CancelToolBar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool confirm = await DisplayAlert("Are you sure?", "All unsaved changes will be lost", "I'm Sure", "Cancel");
            
            if(confirm)
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
```

Edit:

This is what my XAML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Invenutory.Views.Inventory.AddEditInventoryList">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Save"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Clicked="SaveToolBarItem_Clicked"
                     Priority="1"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Cancel"
                     Order="Secondary"
                     Clicked="CancelToolBar_Clicked"
                     Priority="0"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Padding="20">
            <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               Padding="20"  
               CornerRadius="8"
               BorderColor="AliceBlue">
                <StackLayout
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                 Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="Name: " HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" IsTextPredictionEnabled="True" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="Description: " HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Editor HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" IsTextPredictionEnabled="True" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="Count: " HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Count, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20" CornerRadius="8" BorderColor="AliceBlue">
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="150" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Gray" Source="{Binding CapturedPhoto}" />
                    <Button Text="Take Photo" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Command="{Binding TakePhotoCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I just  wrote two pages and your codes work well on my side. Is there any more relevant codes?

Comment: And it is not recommend to use two NavigationPages in one project, try to not warp the AddEditInventoryList in a NavigationPage. You can add a view in the top of AddEditInventoryList  to make it looks like the NavitionBar and buttons(toolbaritem) there.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Gotcha, I thought that might have been an anti pattern. I will add more code when I get home.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I've added my XAML.

Comment: The xaml looks well and have you tried not warp with a NavigationPage?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I will try that, I will also try wrapping it in a RunOnUIThread call

Comment: OK, good luck. Use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by updating my inner `.ContinueWith` to look as follows:

```
confirm.ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if(x.Result)
                {
                    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Don't forget to make this answer later which will help more people with same problem.:)